# Enable SSL connections on PostgreSQL server

Tags: postgresql, ssl-certificate

I am trying to connect my PowerBI with a postgreSQL database. For this reason I need to enable the SSL connections.
So far, I have created the server.key and server.crt files as referred in the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/ssl-tcp.html) 
I have also modified the postgresql.conf file with the following parameters:

```
#authentication_timeout = 1min      # 1s-600s
ssl = on                # (change requires restart)
#ssl_ciphers = 'HIGH:MEDIUM:+3DES:!aNULL' # allowed SSL ciphers
                    # (change requires restart)
#ssl_prefer_server_ciphers = on     # (change requires restart)
#ssl_ecdh_curve = 'prime256v1'      # (change requires restart)
ssl_cert_file = 'server.crt'        # (change requires restart)
ssl_key_file = 'server.key'     # (change requires restart)
#ssl_ca_file = ''           # (change requires restart)
#ssl_crl_file = ''          # (change requires restart)
#password_encryption = on
#db_user_namespace = off
#row_security = on
```

But I have no success, what am I missing?

Postgres version: 9.5
WIndows 8

I am using ODBC to test if the connection with SSL actually works, and as you can see it doesnt:
[image]

I would like to figure out how to get this running, but I also would be happy if I can force Power BI not to user SSL connection. If there is someone who knows how to do it, let me know!

**EDIT**
More information: pg_hba.conf

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
# IPv4 local connections:
#host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
hostssl    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections: host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

Comment: Can't you just turn off the requirement? In your screen shot you have SSL mode set to `require`.  Can't you change that to allow or disable?

Comment: I am using ODBC to test if the SSL conection actually works. I need it for the connection with Power BI

Comment: Are you using a self-signed cert? If so, it might not work. You may need to get a certificate from an authorized certificate authority.

Comment: @Alexander Yes, I was trying it with a self-signed cert. How could I get it from an authorized authority? (which one?)

Comment: Usually you would buy one from a certificate authority. There are several of them, but Namecheap.com is a source I know of. A new service that looks very cool is Let's Encrypt (https://letsencrypt.org/howitworks), which lets you get free SSL certificates. I would recommend giving Let's Encrypt a try first since it's free. After you get the cert, replace your self-signed one with that one.

Comment: Self-signed certificates works fine with PostgreSQL. Possible problems: pg_hba.conf has hostnossl settings; your postgresql server is compiled without ssl support; your odbc library is using libpq compiled without ssl support

Comment: @TomaszMyrta from your comment: pg_hba.conf is also modified (I edited my question), the obdc is just for testing issues, Power BI is also not working, so I guess it is not the cause. It could be that the server is compiled without ssl support? I have downloaded zesterday and I though the ssl support is included by default. I run the .exe file, should I dounwload the source + compile it?

Answer (score 2):

You don't mention having re-built Postgres from source as it says is required in the first paragraph of the documentation you cite:

> PostgreSQL has native support for using SSL connections to encrypt
>   client/server communications for increased security. This requires
>   that OpenSSL is installed on both client and server systems and that
>   **support in PostgreSQL is enabled at build time** (see Chapter 15).

(emphasis mine)

If you are trying to make it work from a pre-packaged distribution, such as an RPM or Debian package, SSL support is not compiled in, so is not available to you.

You need to be sure you have OpenSSL installed, and rebuild PostgreSQL from source, adding the `--with-openssl` command line option to the source tree configuration as described in [15.4. Installation Procedure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/install-procedure.html).

See [Chapter 15. Installation from Source Code](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/installation.html) for a more complete description of the necessary installation procedure.